# como numerar una lista mientras se agregan filas de datos

Tags: asp.net, razor

estoy mostrando valores en una tabla mediante filtros como se muestra en la figura para que me puedan entender mejor, los filtros funcionan perfectamente, la tabla es básica como la muestro a continuación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th hidden>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.idEntidad)
            </th>
            <th>N°</th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nombre)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.sexo)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.numDocument)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.fechaConsulta)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.rol)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <th hidden>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.idEntidad)
                </th>
                <th>

                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.nombre)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.sexo)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.numDocument)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.fechaConsulta)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.rol)
                </th>
            </tr>

        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

pero lo que no tengo idea de como poder numerarlos ya que con cada filtro muestra cantidades diferentes de filas, estuve probando utilizando un bucle foreach pero en realidad no pude tener resultados deseados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siempre puedes ocupar un `for` de toda la vida

```
@for(int i=0; i<Model.Count; i++)
{
   <tr>
     <td>@i</td>

   //etc..
}
```

O si quieres usar un `foreach` puedes crear una variable como contador

```
@{
    int num = 0;
}
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    num++;

    <tr>
       <td>@num</td>

      //etc..
```

Comment: muchas gracias, muy simple y justo lo que queria

Comment: Me alegro te haya servido, suerte con el proyecto!!